# Multithreaded for loop

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to multithread a `for` loop, and this works so far. How can it be improved? Have I done anything incorrectly?

The work is broken up into blocks and the `block` variable is the amount of objects to process per thread.

**Test.class**

```
public class Test extends MultiThreaded {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        List<TestObject> values = new ArrayList<TestObject>();

        for(int i = 1;i < 7;i++)
            values.add(new TestObject(String.valueOf(i)));

        int block = 2;
        int cursor = 0;

        List<TestObject> objectList = new ArrayList<TestObject>();

        for(TestObject v : values) {
            cursor++;
            objectList.add(v);

            if(cursor < block)
                continue;

            final List<TestObject> objectListCopy = new ArrayList<TestObject>();
            objectListCopy.addAll(objectList);

            Task task = new Task() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for(TestObject o : objectListCopy)
                        o.print();
                }
            };

            startTask(task);
            objectList.clear();

            cursor = 0; 
        }

        while(MultiThreaded.processing()) { continue; }

        System.out.println("move on");
    }

    public static class TestObject {
        String line;

        public TestObject(String string) {
            this.line = string;
        }

        public void print() {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }

}
```

**MultiThreaded.class**

```
public class MultiThreaded {

    public static HashSet<Task> tasks = new HashSet<Task>();

    public static class Task extends Thread {
        public boolean running;
        public void run(){  
            return;
        }  
    }

    public static void startTask(Task task) {
        task.start();
        tasks.add(task);
    }

    public static Task getTask(int id) {

        for(Task task : tasks){
            if(task.getId() == id)
                return task;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static boolean processing() {

        boolean processing = false;

        for(Task task: tasks){
            if(task.isAlive())
                processing = true;
        }

        return processing;
    }

}
```

**OUTPUT**

> ```
> 1
> 2
> 5
> 6
> 3
> 4
> move on
> ```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Multi-threaded concepts are complicated at times. If you really want to learn multi-threading, it is important to get it right. Some things can be extremely difficult to get right. I can highly recommend reading *Java Concurrency in Practice*.

#### Overall

It is not that often I see "multi-threaded code" without a single `synchronized` keyword, or a single use of an atomic variable or concurrent data structure. I suggest you read up on all three of those to better understand what you will have to deal with sooner or later.

I think that you are adding a lot of overhead with the way you are constructing your tasks, that it will remove any benefits you get by running it multi-threaded. Creating all the lists that you use simply takes more time than actually running the code.

It is also important to consider that you are using `System.out.println`, this is a `synchronized` call, which means that only a single thread can only run it a time. This tends to be a big concurrency bottle-neck in a lot of multi-threaded code. As your task(s) seems to only be to use `System.out.println`, I think your code would be better of as single-threaded.

#### Oops, missed some!

In your current code, it does not run the `print` method for the last x items in the list. There already, it is broken.

If you have 1024 items and use a "block" value of 100, 24 items will be missed. (Hint: What is the value of your `cursor` variable after your for-loop to start the tasks is finished?)

#### Singleton mindset

This code:

```
public static HashSet<Task> tasks = new HashSet<Task>();
```

By making it `public static` it seems like you are in the "singleton mindset". Avoid this. This has no business being either public or static. Imagine if some code somewhere at some point would call `tasks.clear();` - That could break a lot.

This field is also a big memory leak. You are only adding tasks to it, you are not removing any tasks.

#### Extending for no reason

You are extending the `MultiThreaded` class, but all methods and fields in that class are `static`. Extending it has no real effect besides giving you quick-access to the methods and variables, by not having to write `MultiThreaded.` each time. This is a bad reason for extending a class.

#### getTask

Your `public static Task getTask(int id)` method, although it is not used, suggests that you are using the wrong data-structure. You could use a `Map<Integer, Task>` which will make the `getTask` lookup much more efficient (from \$O(n)\$ to \$O(1)\$).  As you are dealing with multi-threading, better make it a [ConcurrentMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html) as well. You should however ask yourself if you really need this in the first place.

#### Are we working? Are we working? Are we, are we, are we?

This code:

```
while(MultiThreaded.processing()) { continue; }
```

Is a busy-loop. This code will run as quickly as possible and waste CPU power for you. Running this will essentially remove any benefits you get by using multi-threading in the first place. You should check into the [wait-notify](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html) construct. This can be compared to three kids in the backseat of your car ***constantly*** asking you "Are we there yet? Are we there yet? Are we, are we, are we?", I bet you can drive better without such a distraction. (No offense intended against kids)

This busy-loop does not get better by the fact that your `processing()` method is an inefficient way to check if any task is still working. Use [Atomic variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html) to keep track of the number of running tasks.

#### The wheel...

Java 8 provides the concept of [parallel streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html) which significantly makes this easier.

Your main method can be replaced with this:

```
List<TestObject> values = new ArrayList<TestObject>();
for (int i = 1; i < COUNT; i++)
    values.add(new TestObject(String.valueOf(i)));
values.parallelStream().forEach(o -> o.print());
System.out.println("move on");
```

Comment: Very thorough and informative.

Comment: Does it matter which object i invoke .wait() on?

Comment: @ThatGuy343 Yes, that matters very much. It should be the same object you invoke `.notify()` on. When using the correct classes (atomic variables, concurrent collections) you don't need wait and notify that often, but it is still a good thing to know about.